# Wordpress does not print content right

Tags: php, wordpress, function

My problem is that for some reason pages title and content prints upside down. And it prints searchbar twice. Can you please take look at coede bwlow

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">

        <div class="row text-center no-margin">

        <?php 
        $currentPage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,'post_type'=>'post', 'paged' => $currentPage);
        new WP_Query($args);
        if( have_posts() ): $i = 0;

            while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                <?php 
                    if($i==0): $column = 12; $class = '';
                    elseif($i > 0 && $i <= 2): $column = 6; $class = ' second-row-padding';
                    elseif($i > 2): $column = 4; $class = ' third-row-padding';
                    endif;

                ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <div class="col-xs-<?php echo $column; echo $class; ?> blog-item">
                        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                            $urlImg = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
                        endif; ?>
                        <div class="blog-element" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $urlImg; ?>);">

                            <!--<?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h1>' ); ?> -->
                             <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                            <small><?php the_category(' '); ?></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                <?php next_posts_link('« Older Posts'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts »'); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif;
                wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were doing the Wordpress101 course in youtube. In the code you show there is not a search bar. The search bar is in the header that you called here using:

Maybe in the header was repeated the calling to the search form:

```
        <div class="container">
           <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
```

Also, I had the problem that bootstrap wasn't rendering in a good way the menu, so I had to add also in the header.php (no matter if I also refer to the bootstrap in the functions.php file , as I assumed you did it in the tutorial) the lines on the Bootstrap **CDN** in this page: 
http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/07/25/bootstrap-3-3-7-released/

Copy this CDN links:

- Latest compiled and minified CSS
- Optional theme
- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript